# Question about setTimeout that I need answer to

Tags: javascript, location, settimeout, userscripts

So we all know setTimeout waits a certain amount of time before executing something. My question is, does it wait for the above code to finish executing first, before waiting a second to execute something else, or does it just wait for a second, and whether or not the above code has finished executing, it executes the rest of the code anyways?

```
if (1 == 1) {
//huge chunk of code
} //end of if (1 == 1)

var theTime = 1000;
var timeout = setTimeout("location.reload(true);", theTime);
function resetTimeout() {
clearTimeout(timeout);
timeout = setTimeout("location.reload(true);", theTime);
} //end of function resetTimeout()
```

My goal is to get the first part of the code to finish executing, then refresh the page as soon as the first part of the code has finished executing. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the page will reload 1 second after `setTimeout` was called. So it's the "huge chunk of code" time plus 1 second.

To refresh the page as soon as the first part of the code finishes, just call `location.reload` without `setTimeout`:

```js
if (1) {
  //huge chunk of code
}

location.reload(true);
```

EDIT: This approach doesn't wait for asynchronous code to finish. For example, the program below is interrupted by the reload before the alert box pops up.

```js
if (1) {
  setTimeout(() => alert('Test'), 1000);
}

location.reload(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you setTimeout to a very small value (e.g. 1ms, possibly even zero, but haven't checked that) it will execute as soon as your main code is finished.  It won't execute before your main code is finished, because JavaScript is not multi-threaded.

Comment: So if you set it to 1 second, it waits until your code has finished executing, and then waits a second before executing something else?

Comment: If you put it after your heavy code, then yes.  If you put it before the heavy code, then I'm not sure if it will wait for an additional second or not.  It will definitely happen *after* your huge chunk of code though, never before.  It's a good question and I can't seem to find any documentation to say when the timer starts.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is single-threaded and non-preemptive, it's not possible to interrupt code that's running. Asynchronous code, such as timeouts and AJAX callbacks, cannot run until the currently executing code returns to the main event loop.

The timer in `setTimeout` starts immediately when it's called. But because of the single-threaded design, the callback can't be called until all your current JS finishes. If that takes longer than the timer, then the callback will be delayed. So all you're guaranteed is that the callback will be called in at least that amount of time -- it might be longer, but not shorter. There could also be other asynchronous callbacks ahead of it in the event queue.